# get response via file_get_content with https for sendgrid.com (php)

Tags: php, json, url, file-get-contents

for some reason this code does not work:

```
$url = "https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?api_user=myUserName&api_key=myPassword&list=MyList&data[]={\"email\":\"my@email.here\",\"name\":\"Matthijs de Zwart\"}";
$result = file_get_content($url);
$response = json_decode( $result );
var_dump($response);
```

while if I open a browser and go to this URL

https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?api_user=myUserName&api_key=myPassword&list=MyList&data[]={"email":"my@email.here","name":"Matthijs de Zwart"}

I do get a respond.

I've used these checks

```
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($w);
```

which resulted in the following output:

```
openssl: yes
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: yes
wrappers: array(22) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "compress.zlib"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "compress.bzip2"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "dict"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "ftp"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "ftps"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "gopher"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "http"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "https"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "imap"
  [9]=>
  string(5) "imaps"
  [10]=>
  string(4) "pop3"
  [11]=>
  string(5) "pop3s"
  [12]=>
  string(4) "rtsp"
  [13]=>
  string(4) "smtp"
  [14]=>
  string(5) "smtps"
  [15]=>
  string(6) "telnet"
  [16]=>
  string(4) "tftp"
  [17]=>
  string(3) "php"
  [18]=>
  string(4) "file"
  [19]=>
  string(4) "glob"
  [20]=>
  string(4) "data"
  [21]=>
  string(3) "zip"
}
```

I've been googling around to get it working, but so far I can only find solutions that say to turn on openssl...and it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

// helper function
function curlGet($url)
{
    // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // ssl opts
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    // finished
    return $output;    
}

// usage
var_dump(curlGet("https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?api_user=myUserName&api_key=myPassword&list=MyList&data[]={\"email\":\"my@email.here\",\"name\":\"Matthijs de Zwart\"}"));

?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the hand. After uncomment extension=php_curl.dll in the php.ini file and restarting apache, this is the output: ==> string(0) "" <== While I expect this: {"inserted": 1}

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with a work around, using this code:

```
$dataString = urlencode('{"email":"my@email.here","name":"Matthijs de Zwart"}');

$homepage = file_get_contents("https://sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json?api_user=myUserName&api_key=myPassword&list=MyList&data[]=".$dataString);
```

returns what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using their apiv3. It USED to be good.
But really I would look for a new provider. We moved away from them after they locked us out of our account and their 48 hour support said "create a new account"